# computing probability of not hitting a line segment

Tags: probability

consider two points $a$ and $b$ having integer coordinates inside two circles each of radius $r$ centred at $C_1$ and $C_2$ respectively in two dimensional Euclidean space. There are few line segments present in the environment also, whose endpoints are known. I need to calculate the probability of the line segment joining $a$ and $b$ not intersecting any of those line segments.

**my approach**

My solution is based on simple counting and thus brute force. I have considered every pair of points between the two circles and checked whether there is an intersection or not. I just count the number of non intersecting point pairs and divided it by number of all possible pairs.

**my need**

Clearly the above approach becomes infeasible when $r$ is large.
Is there any better way to compute the probability? Can we obtain some closed form expression?

Comment: Is there a graph or picture or another resource to help. Where are you exactly stuck? Show us your working until now.

Comment: When you say "integral two dimensional Euclidean space" do you mean that only points with integer coordinates exist? This raises a number of questions, such as what is a "circle" in this geometry; and can one line "cross over" another without intersecting it because in a complete Euclidean geometry (real coordinates, not just integers) the lines would have intersected at a non-integer point.

Comment: @DavidK sorry, my bad, i meant to say the points $a$ and $b$ have integral coordinates, updated the question